# PageMethods Not Working with VS2013 web application

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, scriptmanager, pagemethods

I have spent all day struggling with this Error and have read almost every article and tried every hint I found but still not able to make it work.

Please Note: *EnablePageMethod=true inside ScriptManager, Method is public and static and decorated with [WebMethods]*

Same coding is working all perfect with VS2010 and with empty project in VS2013 but when using with **New Project -> web -> web forms** the output is attached here for your reference.
[image: Error OutPut]

> Here is my code.

**Code Behind:**

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string GetCurrentTime(string name)
        {
            return "Hello " + name + Environment.NewLine + "The Current Time is: "
                + DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowCurrentTime() {
            PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").value, OnSuccess);
           }
           function OnSuccess(response, userContext, methodName) {
               alert(response);
           }
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
        Your Name : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick="ShowCurrentTime()" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the code-front of the page you are using? I mean the full markup of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding both `[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]` and `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]` to the server side `GetCurrentTime` method.

Also make sure your script manager has `EnablePageMethods="True"`. Your question states you set *EnablePageMethod=true* which is incorrectly spelled (should be plural).

Comment: Try opening your browser developer tools to see what errors are logged to the console. Adding the logged error messages to your question would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fail the click event handler to prevent the postback/page submit.

Just return false from your javascript function:

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    PageMethods.GetCurrentTime(document.getElementById("<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>").value, OnSuccess);
    return false; // added
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the button does not post back when calling a PageMethod from client-side. With your current markup, it will post back and cause unexpected effects.

You should be using the following markup for button, so it never posts back. Then the call to pagemethod should work. In markup below the button click event is returning a false value, so the page never gets submitted i.e. posted back.

Also, it would be best if you post your page markup in full, since there may be an issue with the markup.

```
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time"
                    onclick="ShowCurrentTime();return false;" />
```